# Explanation for the solution

Tags: education

The world's population has grown at an average rate of $1.9$ percent per year since $1945$. There were approximately $4$ billion people in the world in $1975$. Which of the following functions represents the world's population $P$, in the billions of people, $t$ years since $1975$?

A) $P(t) = 4(1.019)^t$

B) $P(t) = 4(1.9)$

C) $P(t) = 1.19t + 4$

D) $P(t) = 1.019t + 4$

The answer is A, but I want to know the solution method.

I understand the idea of the question, but I want to know why we used $1.019$ and not $1.9$ in the answer

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognize and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: If there was $4$ billion people, since the solution is in the billions, you will take $4$ and multiply it by the percentage of increase plus one. Since 100% is considered as 1, then 1.9% is 0.019. So to get increase after first year you calculate $4\cdot 1.019$, for second year $4\cdot 1.019\cdot 1.019$, for t year $4\cdot (1.019)^t$.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos thanks, give me 1 minute

Answer (score 0):

To say that quantity $P$ increased by $R$ percent over a year means that the difference between the new and old value is $r$ times the old value, where $r = \frac R{100}$ is the percentage converted to a ratio. So
$$\begin{align}P(0) &= P\\
P(1) - P(0) &= rP(0)\\P(1) &= P(0) + rP(0)\\&= (1+r)P(0)\\&= (1+r)P\end{align}$$
If the following years all can be treated as being at the same rate of increase, then $$\begin{align}
P(2) &= (1+r)P(1) = (1+r)(1+r)P=(1+r)^2P\\
P(3) &= (1+r)P(2) = (1+r)(1+r)^2P=(1+r)^3P\\
P(4) &= (1+r)P(3) = (1+r)(1+r)^3P=(1+r)^4P\\
&\ \ \vdots\\
P(t) &= (1+r)^tP = P(1+r)^t
\end{align}$$